# Calculate the Riemann tensor and Ricci tensor

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, differential-geometry, curvature

Given a metric tensor $\gamma_{ij}$ (where $i, j = 1, 2, 3$; the metric tensor of 3- dimensional space is denoted by $\gamma_{ij}$ to distinguish it from the metric tensor $g_{\mu\nu}$ of 4-dimensional space-time), show that the Riemann tensor is equal to

\begin{equation} ^{(3)}R_{ijkl}=\frac{\xi}{R^2}\left(\gamma_{ik}\gamma_{jl}-\gamma_{il}\gamma_{jk}\right),\end{equation}

and

\begin{equation}^{(3)}R_{ij}=2\frac{\xi}{R^2}\gamma_{ij}\end{equation}
where $\xi=0,\pm 1$, distinguishes 3-plane, 3-sphere and 3-hyperboloid.

The first equation above looks quite simple, but I have no idea how to derive it. Can you please suggest me how to start deriving the above expressions?

Comment: This should be in any textbook on general relativity or differential geometry, such as [the freely available lecture notes by S. Caroll](http://xxx.lanl.gov/abs/gr-qc/9712019).

Comment: Hint: use the Cartan formalism on the general metric, using the structure equations. It's probably the fastest method.